# create tile menu in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create a layout like this:

[image]

I'm new in android and I create a layout.

This is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_home"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="#721480" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#721422"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#723422"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#724422" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="#723111"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#754300" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#700000"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="#724500" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

but it's not fit to I want. I have two problem :

1. I do not know how to force button's width and height be in the same size.
2. Why padding in buttons do not work?

Can anyone one help me to find out?

Comment: The best way to achieve layout like this is to use `<TableLayout >` which widely gives you many option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [`android:weightSum`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum) on your layout along with `android:layout_weight`.

This atribute can help you to make the elements fill the same space everytime.

See this example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It'll create a layout with 3 `Button`. The first one will fill half of the layout, and the other two will fill the rest of the space. Like this:

[image]

**P.S.:** `fill_parent` is deprecated, use `match_parent` instead.

**EDIT:** Padding won't likely work as you expect on this approach. But if you want to increase the spacing between the buttons, you can simply use `android:layout_margin`.

See the difference between those two on the image below.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot!but i need padding between button not around button. giving padding in linear layout do not affect padding between button.

Comment: You need padding or margin? Here's the difference: http://i.stack.imgur.com/PeSIJ.gif

Answer (score 0):

Combining `padding` and `weight` on the same element could prove to be tricky sometimes.

To answer your first question - hot to make the elements square - create your custom button extending `Button` and override the `onMeasure` method:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    if(width > height) {
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

To answer your second question - it is tricky when combined with weight. By using the weight attribute you tell the button to go take 1/3 or 2/3 of the space no matter what its content is. Padding in this case doesn't mean anything per se, because by definition the padding is the amount of space between a view's content (actual text or image) and its edge. And since you just told the button to extend the edge for 1/3 or 2/3 of the parent... 
Without trying I would guess that you might see the padding if the view's content would not fit and it would have to be scrolled. You could possibly go around it by having another layer of layouts dealing with the weight and let your buttons dealing with the padding. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ... >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="?"
            android:layout_height="?"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/?" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        ... >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="?"
            android:layout_height="?"
            android:background="#721480" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```